# GIMP transparency is not working

Tags: gimp, transparency

I followed [**this**](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Transparent-Image-Using-Gimp) tutorial on GIMP to make an image transparent. Here is a snippet of the original image opened inside Windows Image Viewer (so the grey background is part of Windows Image Viewer, I wanted the white background to show up which was hard to notice if I had just uploaded the original image here rather than a snippet image),

[image]

Inside GIMP the image appears to be transparent (again this is a snippet so the grey background is not part of the image),

[image]

But when I export the image and open it again in Windows Image Viewer the white background is still present. I need the white background to disappear so that when I add it as an icon in a program it blends in seamlessly.

**Update:**

Kudos to Volker Siegel!

It turns out I was exporting as a JPG. After exporting as a PNG I got the full transparency shown here in MS Image Viewer again (so MS IV has a greyish background and you can see the image is transparent),

[image]

Comment: Can you add the image you exported? How did you export it? It should be a PNG, JPG does not support transparency.

Comment: It is a JPG :/ I guess that's the problem. Thank you!

Comment: That was the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not write which way you export the image, but this is important.

It needs to be exported to an image format that supports saving the **transparency** information to the file.

Otherwise, the export process has to **find a way** to save the image **without the transparency** - asking you, or just pretending the background is white, for example.

The most common image file format **supporting** transparency is **PNG**,
and the most common format **not supporting** it is **JPG**.

The problem could be that the **image was exported to JPG**, and lost the transparency while exporting.
If that's right, exporting to PNG instead should help.

---

As a side note, it's interesting that the handling of transparency was **not "just left out"** from JPEG - it's more like the whole **concept of lossy compressing does not go together with the idea of transparency**.
The basic idea of lossy compression is to store information that is more visible in a more detailed way, and leave out information that is less visible. But if a pixel can be transparent, we **do not know** about what is visible - it depends on the **background that we do not have**.