# Gimp "transparent background" is exporting to jpg as white. I want transparent. did tutorials

Tags: gimp, background

Why is my transparent background with the checkerboard, showing as white when it gets exported to jpg?

Comment: cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_graphics_file_formats#Technical_details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIMP transparency is not working](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37471/gimp-transparency-is-not-working)

Answer (score 10):

JPGs do not support transparency. If you want to retain transparency, save to a format that supports transparency such as PNG.